# Making a bullet fire in the direction a sprite is facing

Tags: c++, sfml

How exactly would this be achieved? Here is the code I have so far which just rotates the ship based on where the mouse is, as well as the bullet:

```
xPos = ship.getPosition().x, yPos = ship.getPosition().y, mousex = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).x, mousey = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).y;
if (mousex > 800) mousex = 800; if (mousey > 600) mousey = 600; if (mousex < 0) mousex = 0; if (mousey < 0) mousey = 0;
double angle = atan2(mousey - yPos, mousex - xPos) * (180/3.14159);
ship.setRotation(90+angle);
bullet.setRotation(-90+angle);
```

So, how would I match the bullet's velocity to be the same as the direction the ship is facing? So that if I fire a bullet it should fire exactly where the ship is looking towards.

What I've tried so far is creating a distance vector from the bullet to the mouse position, and moving the bullet by that distance vector, but of course that would instantly move the bullet to the mouse's position in just 1 frame. It needs to be like a normal velocity that still goes towards the mouse position.

Comment: Seems like basic trigonometry to me. Either do `velocity_x = cos(angle)*speed; velocity_y = sin(angle)*speed;` or normalize the vector `[mousex-xPos,mousey-yPos]` and multiply its components with the speed

Answer (score 1):

So, as you correctly described what you need is a normalized delta in the direction of the angle.

Either you use the properties of the unity circle and calculate it like

```
velocity_x = cos(angle)*speed;
velocity_y = sin(angle)*speed;
```

or you use the approach that you started and do

```
diff_x = mousex - xPos;
diff_y = mousey - yPos;
magnitude = sqrt(diff_x*diff_x + diff_y*diff_y);
velocity_x = diff_x/magnitude * speed; 
velocity_y = diff_y/magnitude * speed;
```